# Troubleshooting Missing Rows with MS Sync Framework

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm using the Microsoft Sync Framework version 2 to synchronize data between a server database running SQL Server 2008 and a SQLCE 3.5 database on an occasionally connected WPF app.

This is working fine for the most part, but rows from a particular table don't seem to be getting pushed back up to the server database when inserted on the client.  Rows from other tables make it up there just fine.

I've tried a few things so far:

- I've made sure that I'm setting the SyncDirection for the table to Bidirectional
- I've refreshed the SyncTable definition by removing and re-adding the table though the "Configure Database Synchronization" wizard.
- Ensured that rows inserted into the SQLCE database conform to all NOT NULL and foreign key constraints in the server database.
- Confirmed that change tracking is enabled on the table on the server.

What else should I check that could cause data not to be synced back to the server for a particular table?